# How to manage dependency when cloning repository?

Tags: python, mercurial, repository, repository-pattern, distutils

I am using mercurial and I am wondering how to do the following.
Here is my repository architecture :

```
./repo/utils/workers/[...]
./repo/utils/tools/[...]
./repo/proj1/file.py
```

Let's say that in proj1/file.py I need to import some code located in workers and tools. eg

```
from utils.workers import foo
from utils.tools import bar
```

What would be the best way/tool to check out proj1 with all the needed dependencies (eg, workers/ and tools/) without having to clone utils/workers and utils/tools inside of proj1.

Also - doing a `sys.path.append(repo/utils/workers)` is not a option.

== Edit 01/24/11 ==

Thanks for all the answers.
I've been thinking of a way to really explain my problem differently, and it seams that we should make abstraction of hg for a better understanding. 
Let's say that in `/utils/` there also are another few modules in there, that do not belong to my project, but that are actually needed. For example: http://code.google.com/p/python-gflags/
When checking out `/repo/proj1/` I want all the dependencies, not matter which repository they're form, to be checked out too - but with read-only since.

So if I do `hg clone /proj1/` I want this action to also clone all the needed modules from `/utils/workers/`,
`/utils/tools/`,
 and python-gflags under
 `/utils/python-gflags`

I hope this helps a little bit to clarify what I am trying to do.

Cheers,

Martin

Comment: `sys.path.append('/path/to/repo')` is sufficient if you'd like to run from a checkout. Also you could use `pip` and `virtualenv`. `pip` supports installing from a mercurial repo, a checkout, inplace, etc. `virtualenv` allows you to have multiple version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I've found to to this, is by using buildout.

http://www.buildout.org

It is a really helpful solution to manage dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [subrepositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository) (which also called [nested](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/NestedRepositories))

Comment: Subrepositories as far as I understand do not fit this purpose since they are supposed to be nested repositories, not  imported as extra modules - which should also be read only. Thanks for the hint tho - I looked into subrepo but it didn't fit my needs unfortunately :(

Comment: Hmm... are you sure subrepos don't do what you want? One "project repo" named "repo", with three subrepos "workers", "tools" and "proj1"? I've used them for almost this exact purpose. (In my case, 'tools' was an svn repo controlled by another group)

Comment: If you can't/won't use subrepos, you're left with a pure manual process. The help you would get from Mercurial is subrepos.

Comment: @Martin - subrepos don't have to be read only, you can commit to them just like a normal repo. They exhibit some quirks, but nothing that prevents you from using them for this purpose.